# Azure WebJobs 3.x does not trigger with CRON expression in Azure Application Settings

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-continuous

**Environment**: .Net Framework 4.7.2

**Application settings being read from**: app.config, no applicationsettings.json in the project

**Issue**: Environment variable doesn't override the CRON expression in project.exe.config (one in Kudu) and trigger. All other app settings are getting overridden but CRON expression.

Here is my builder:

```
var builder = new HostBuilder();
var resolver = new myNameResolver();
builder.ConfigureWebJobs(buil =>
{
   buil.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
   buil.AddAzureStorage();
   buil.AddServiceBus(servBus=>
   {
     servBus.MessageHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = false;
     servBus.MessageHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = myMaxConcurrentCalls;
     servBus.ConnectionString = myServiceBusConnectionString;
     servBus.MessageHandlerOptions.MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
    });
    buil.AddTimers();
});
builder.ConfigureServices(serv => serv.AddSingleton<INameResolver>(resolver));
builder.ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
{
  config.AddInMemoryCollection(BuildConfiguration(myStorageConnectionString));
  config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
});
builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(buil => buil.AddEnvironmentVariables());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you notice the ***settings.job*** file after click ***publish as Azure WebJob...*** in Visual Studio? I'm afraid the CRON setting haven't been read.

You should  use that file to set schedule for your WebJob, and set your ***settings.job*** file properties in Visual Studio as ***Copy if newer***.
[image]

This file will be stored in Kudu, too.
[image]More details about WebJobs you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs#scheduling-a-triggered-webjob).

For your question multiple functions with multiple schedules in one WebJob, it seems not possible.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm running a continuous webjob and require the cron to trigger a function. Will this resolve for continuous webjob as well?

Comment: Of course it works for continuous webjob, cause I use continuous webjob for testing this.@user3627341

Comment: How about a scenario wherein I have multiple functions and multiple cron expressions. I would like to not give "schedule" in settings.job but other app settings keys that shall contain cron expressions. This is another issue I faced now.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible to set multiple cron expressions in one WebJob, @user3627341. You can refer to the picture I updated in my answer.

Comment: Hey, @user3627341 .If you think my answer is useful, please accept it by clicking on the ✔, so more people would see it.